# csrf_token() is not replaced with the token value In react with laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, axios

I want to send a post request to laravel endpoint from React app.
Here is what i did
1, i add a meta tag in index.html, `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`
2, in the axios.post method 
axios.request({

```
headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
        },
        method: 'post',
        url: `http://${IP_ADDRESS}/api/register`,
        data: user,
    })
```

Here is the problem X-CSRF-TOKEN has a value of `{{ csrf_token() }}` but it must be an actual token?

Answer (score 0):

You are using blade syntax in `html` file that's why it is not working.

Comment: So what shall i do?

Comment: You can only use this in either php file or blade file like <?php csrf_token(); ?>

Comment: Or you can exclude using csrf token for this request.

Comment: The servers sends unauthorized if the token is left.

Comment: For that first you need to remove that request to be verified for csrf token. Check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf. You need to add the request in except array.

Comment: @KamalPaliwal That is a really bad idea and definitely not something you should recommend.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye I'm not experienced with Laravel in particular, but see if you can use X-XSRF-TOKEN instead, which is accessible to you in a cookie (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf)

Comment: Thank you @Jakub Judsa. I will let you know ASAP.